# can RESTful API Response Body is Auto translation?

Tags: api, rest, http

i got response from restful api, like this:
(key, value pair with code and country name)

```
{
  "C0010": "Afganistan",
  "C0020": "Albania",
  "C0030": "Algeria",
  "C0050": "Andorra",
  "C0060": "Angola",
  "C2060": "Anguilla",
  "C0070": "Antigua and Barbuda",
  "C0080": "Argentina",
  ...
}
```

but in chrome browser, response body is translated Korean(my real location, not my browser language).

```
{
  "C0630": "가나",
  "C0590": "가봉",
  "C0700": "가이아나",
  "C0600": "감비아",
  "C0670": "과테말라",
  "C0660": "그레나다",
  "C0640": "그리스",
  "C0650": "그린란드",
  "C0680": "기니",
  ...
}
```

Not only automatic translation, but also sorting is done automatically.

Changing the language of your browser or changing the browser itself doesn't make any difference. I had put some headers(like "Accept-Language"), but nothing changes. Why does this happen?

Comment: please expose the endpoint to take a look